# Parcel vs. Serializeable for exchanging objects among services/activities

Tags: android, serialization, location, parcelable

Let me first give you the whole picture: I am developing a location based application, that invokes a constant recreation and exchange of objects, among several activities and services. The necessary data to create the objects being exchanged, is stored in an SQLite database, that in its turn gets populated by retrieving data from a remote SQL database.

It got quickly obvious, that passing raw attributes of an object to activities/services (via intents), was a huge coding overhead, diminishing every extension prospects the application might have. So, soon i decided to extend my main object class to implement a [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) one, as shown below:

```
public class MyProduct implements Parcelable {
    //MyProduct Attributes
    private int myProductId;
    private String myProductDescription;
    private float myProductRadius;
    //More attributes...
    public MyProduct() {
        myProductId=-1;
        myProductDescription="defaultProductDescription";
        myProductRadius=10;
        //More attributes
    }
    public int describeContents(){
        return 0;
    }
    // write your object's data to the passed-in Parcel
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
        //Product attributes
        try{
        out.writeInt(myProductId);
        out.writeString(myProductDescription);
        out.writeFloat(myProductRadius);
        //More attributes
        }  
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
    // this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyProduct> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyProduct>() {
        //public class MyCreator implements Parcelable.Creator<MyProduct> {    
        public MyProduct createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyProduct(in);
        }

        public MyProduct[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyProduct[size];
        }
    };

        // example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
        private MyProduct(Parcel in) {
        //in.readParcelable(MyProduct.class.getClassLoader());
        try{
            //MyProduct.class.getClassLoader();
            myProductId=in.readInt();
            myProductDescription=in.readString();
            myProductRadius=in.readFloat();
            //More attributes
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
    //Setters and Getters
}//endOfMyProduct.class
```

Although i checked every data entry to the parcel fields, the following exception keeps spawning:

```
01-05 19:35:11.570: ERROR/Parcel(59): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.nifo.distribution.MyProduct, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nifo.distribution.MyProduct
```

For this reason, i consider of the MyProduct.class implementing [serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html), hoping that it will turn to be a more error-forgiving structure. What would be the pros and cons of such alternation in the case described above?

Comment: Why not just pass the primary key in an extra, and have whoever needs the data get it from the database?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Because i would like to reduce the queries to the local SQLite database, as much as possible, in the way of passing the actual object each time. However, am not sure if this is more expensive in terms of consumption, computational and coding overhead than what you are proposing.

Comment: Wouldn't querying be cheaper than passing an object all over creation?

Comment: Passing the object through intents will be orders of magnitude slower than re-querying the database. I would guess something like 4 or 5 orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: After taking your comments into consideration, i 've decided to modify the application implementing what CommonsWare initially proposed. Thank you all for sharing your thoughts on this :)

Comment: That means...everytime we pass the objects, write to sqlite database each time and retrieve by query?